# Error on migration file: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I'm trying to create a migration with typeorm. Here's my file:

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from "typeorm"

export class changeAddressNumberDatatype1654614315001 implements MigrationInterface {
    async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "accounts" MODIFY "address_number" varchar(50)`,
            `ALTER TABLE "service-request" MODIFY "address_number" varchar(50)`
        )
    }

    async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(
            `ALTER TABLE "accounts" MODIFY "address_number" int`,
            `ALTER TABLE "service-request" MODIFY "address_number" int`
        )
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> src/migration/1654614315001-changeAddressNumberDatatype.ts:7:13 -
> error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'any[]'.

If I modify only one table at a time it doesn't give me any errors. Is that the way to do it? Or can I modify multiple tables on the same migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to modify columns of multiple tables with the method `query`.

The correct way to do what you want it's doing the modify it one by one:

```
export class changeAddressNumberDatatype1654614315001
  implements MigrationInterface
{
  async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(
      `ALTER TABLE "accounts" MODIFY "address_number" varchar(50)`,
    );
    await queryRunner.query(
      `ALTER TABLE "service-request" MODIFY "address_number" varchar(50)`,
    );
  }

  async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(
      `ALTER TABLE "accounts" MODIFY "address_number" int`,
    );
    await queryRunner.query(
      `ALTER TABLE "service-request" MODIFY "address_number" int`,
    );
  }
}
```

if you don't want to use a string for this you could use the method `changeColumn` or `changeColumns` from multiple columns of the same table.